# Abstract classes in Swift

Tags: java, ios, swift

I've been working in `Java` for past few years, and now am learning `Swift`. I was trying to implement `Java` abstract classes in `Swift` and found out that `Swift` doesn't support it. I've also seen that the `abstract` classes can be achieved through `protocol`, but as my class contains generic type, I am bit confused about it.

I've created a `Java` class structure and tried to convert it to Swift, But I failed. Here's the class

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args){
        D d = new D();
        d.sayHello();
        d.sayHi();
        d.sayGracias();

        System.out.println(d.get("Hello"));
     }

     static class A{
         public void sayHello(){
             System.out.println("Hello from A");
         }
     }

     static class B<R> extends A{
        public void sayHi(){
            System.out.println("Hi from B");
        }   
     }

     static abstract class C<M,R> extends B<R>{

         public abstract List<M> get(R r);

         public void sayGracias(){
            System.out.println("Gracias from C");
         } 
     }

     static class D extends C<String, String>{

         @Override 
         public List<String> get(String s){
             List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
             list.add(s);
             return list;
         }
     }

}
```

## Output

```
Hello from A
Hi from B
Gracias from C
[Hello]
```

Asking all my doubts and questions about this topic would be a mess. So the converted code `(Java -> Swift)` will fix all my doubts. Could anyone help me by converting the above code to `Swift`?

NOTE: I need forced overriding like in Java.

Comment: There are no abstract classes in Swift (just like Objective-C). Your best bet is going to be to use a Protocol, which is like a Java Interface.

Comment: I tried, but as my class contains generic type and protocol doesn't support generic type, i couldn't finish it. :/ I need to get the `Swift` version of the `Java` code. It'll answer all the questions buzzing in my head.

Comment: protocol is just like a function and the functions support generic types

Comment: You can use j2objc library to convert your java classes to object c and from that your can create bridging-header and access that classes in swift. See at: https://developers.google.com/j2objc/

Comment: @dixith I need generic and forced overriding brother. I’ve read the article before

Comment: @all I’ve many doubts , the converted code would help me. Please anyone answer with the swift version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strongly suggest you redesign your model in Swift. Just like when translating spoken languages, the outcome can sound very awkward, programming languages, when translated, can look awkward too. If you still want to translate from Java, read on.

---

The really hard problem to solve here is that `B` is generic. If `B` wasn't generic, everything would work way better in Swift.

For now, you just have to use a `class` and pretend it is a protocol:

```
class A {
    func sayHello() {
        print("Hello from A")
    }
}

class B<R> : A {
    func sayHi() {
        print("Hi from B")
    }
}

class C<M, R> : B<R> {
    // this fatalError() thing is really ugly, but I can't think of any other workarounds
    func get(r: R) -> [M] { fatalError() }
    func sayGracias() {
        print("Gracias from C")
    }
}

class D : C<String, String> {
    override func get(r: String) -> [String] {
        return [r]
    }
}

let d = D()
d.sayHello()
d.sayHi()
d.sayGracias()
print(d.get(r: "Hello"))
```

If `B` were not generic (you are not using the generic argument anyway), then this can be done:

```
class A {
    func sayHello() {
        print("Hello from A")
    }
}

class B : A {
    func sayHi() {
        print("Hi from B")
    }
}

protocol C {
    // associated types in Swift are kind of like generic parameters for protocols
    associatedtype M
    associatedtype R
    func get(r: R) -> [M]
}

extension C {
    func sayGracias() {
        print("Gracias from C")
    }
}

// You have to specify that D inherits from B as well since protocols can't inherit from classes
class D : B, C {
    typealias M = String
    typealias R = String

    func get(r: String) -> [String] {
        return [r]
    }
}

let d = D()
d.sayHello()
d.sayHi()
d.sayGracias()
print(d.get(r: "Hello"))
```

Comment: B is generic in my case. Even if the class `D` doesn't implement/override the method `get(r: String)`, it still compiles. Is there anything to block the compilation? .I think that's what `abstract` does in java.

Comment: @theapache64 I don't think so. Things like SwiftLint *might* help you do that, I'm not sure. Why not try to redesign your model?

Comment: Redesigning the model might fix the problem. but I wanted to have a solution with this model. I just wanted to know if it's possible or any method that I was unaware of. Thank you for your response mate. :)